# Database automatically update by Spring/Hibernate when I change a field of an Object in a class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

I have a class called `VoceMenuUtente`, annotated as @Entity, with 2 fields:

1. **Descrizione**
2. **Titolo**

I make a select to get the data inside the database. Before printing them on the screen I have to add a string to the value got from the database, so I do this:

```
voceMenuUtente.setDescrizione = voceMenuUtente.getDescrizione + "blablabla";
```

I made that in a class called `TransactionPreDAO`. I have a pointcut for that class:

```
<tx:advice id="txAdviceTransactionPreDAO" transaction-manager="transactionManager" >
            <tx:attributes>
                <tx:method name="*"/>
            </tx:attributes>
        </tx:advice>    
        <aop:config>
            <aop:pointcut id="transactionPreDAOTxPointcut" expression="execution(* com.springgestioneerrori.preDAO.TransactionPreDAO.*(..))" />
            <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdviceTransactionPreDAO" pointcut-ref="transactionPreDAOTxPointcut" />
        </aop:config>
```

After this, my database is updated automatically and in the field **Descrizione** I don't have anymore the original value, but I have the original value plus "blablabla"?

Why this happens? I don't have any "update" method for the object `VoceMenuUtente`. Maybe it depends on the pointcut. I'm still studying Spring, so probably I made some mistakes.

Does it depend on the fact that I missed `read-only="true"` in the  tag `<tx:method name="*"/>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you load the object from database via `get`, query, criteria etc., the object state is associated with the persistence context, and any changes to it are automatically propagated to DB.

You don't have to explicitly call `update` on that object. `update` is used to re-attach a detached object with the session. An object which had been persisted before, but is not currently associated with the Hibernate session.

If you want to override that default behavior, you can call `session.evict(voceMenuUtente)`. This will make the object detached (evict the object from the persistence context).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. According to what I read on the internet, I can also use read-only="true", can't I? According to my code, it would be a better solution

Comment: Yes, if you only have that single select you can use read-only transaction in that case. Hibernate will not perform dirty checking in that case, so no update as well